# Scaffold by Rails - Bootstrap application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, scaffold

Did somebody knows how to solve scaffold problem by the choice gem 'rails', '5.2.0' and 'bootstrap', '4.3.1', probably originated due to impossibility to make a scaffold.scss file.

My knowledge in Rails is too poor to understand explanation in the end of the execution of the:

```
rails generate scaffold Something first second
```

In the end the scaffolding is broken with explanation:

**1. With bootsnap**

```
  ...
        invoke    scss
        create      app/assets/stylesheets/somethings.scss
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass/css (LoadError)
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:80:in `register'
  ...
```

**2. Without bootsnap**

```
      ...
        invoke    scss
        create      app/assets/stylesheets/somethings.scss
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass/css (LoadError)
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when I tried to run `rails generate scaffold --help`. It was

```
.../ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass/css (LoadError)
```

I don't have bootsnap in my Gemfile, but I do have the sassc-rails gem.

```
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sassc-rails', '~> 2.1'
```

The latest version of sassc-rails is 2.1.2. Try running `bundle update sassc-rails`. That is what fixed it for me.